# Extract string between nth and ith instance of delimiter

Tags: r, regex

I have a vector of strings, similar to this one, but with many more elements:

```
s <- c("CGA-DV-558_T_90.67.0_DV_1541_07", "TC-V-576_T_90.0_DV_151_0", "TCA-DV-X_T_6.0_D_A2_07", "T-V-Z_T_2_D_A_0", "CGA-DV-AW0_T.1_24.4.0_V_A6_7", "ACGA-DV-A4W0_T_274.46.0_DV_A266_07")
```

And I would like to use a function that extracts the string between the nth and ith instances of the delimiter "_". For example, the string between the 2nd (n = 2) and 3rd (i = 3) instances, to get this:

```
[1] "90.67.0"  "90.0"     "6.0"      "2"        "24.4.0"   "274.46.0"
```

Or if n = 4 and i = 5"

```
[1] "1541" "151"  "A2"   "A"    "A"    "A266"
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: One way is with `strsplit` and `sapply`. `sapply(strsplit(s, split="_"), "[", 3)` or with `read.table`, `read.table(text=s, sep="_", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)[, 3]`.

Comment: Works well if "i" is always equals to n+1. But it would not work if I want the string between lets say the 2nd and 4th instances of "_"

Comment: You can always pull out longer vectors, like `sapply(strsplit(s, split="_"), "[", 3:4)` for example. If you wanted to put them back together, use `paste`.

Comment: This gives me a table, whereas for example for n = 3 and i = 5, I would like to get "DV_1541" "DV_151"  "D_A2"    "D_A"     "V_A6"    "DV_A266"

Comment: It returns a matrix, and you can use `paste` to put it back together as I mentioned. `apply(sapply(strsplit(s, split="_"), "[", 3:4), 2, paste, collapse="_")`.

Comment: That works, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#FUNCTION
foo = function(x, n, i){
    do.call(c, lapply(x, function(X)
        paste(unlist(strsplit(X, "_"))[(n+1):(i)], collapse = "_")))
}

#USAGE
foo(x = s, n = 3, i = 5)
#[1] "DV_1541" "DV_151"  "D_A2"    "D_A"     "V_A6"    "DV_A266"
```

Comment: Works when i = n+1, but otherwise it returns more than one string for each element, for example if using foo(x = s, n = 3, i = 5).

Comment: "DV_1541" "DV_151"  "D_A2"    "D_A"     "V_A6"    "DV_A266"

Comment: A small question, can we use this function to extract the last part of the string, to get "07" "0"  "07" "0"  "7"  "07"?

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with `gsub`

```
n = 2
i = 3

pattern1 = paste0("(.*?_){", n,  "}")
temp = gsub(pattern1, "", s)
pattern2 = paste0("((.*?_){", i-n,  "}).*")
temp = gsub(pattern2, "\\1", temp)
temp = gsub("_$", "", temp)
[1] "1541" "151"  "A2"   "A"    "A6"   "A266"
```

Answer (score 4):

A third method, that uses `substring` for the extraction and `gregexpr` to find the positions is

```
# extract postions of "_" from each vector element, returns a list
spots <- gregexpr("_", s, fixed=TRUE)

# extract text in between third and fifth underscores
substring(s, sapply(spots, "[", 3) + 1, sapply(spots, "[", 5) - 1)
"DV_1541" "DV_151"  "D_A2"    "D_A"     "V_A6"    "DV_A266"
```