# How to change the stop value of substr function in R depending of the vector's value?

Tags: r, functional-programming, substr, strsplit

I built a way of determining the stop value for a substring depending on the length of the string in a vector: the idea is to keep all the characters before the second dash. The number of characters isn't the same for all datasets.

```
textLength <- which(strsplit(data$`N° échantillon`, "")[[1]] == "-")[2] - 1
data$`N° échantillon` <- substr(data$`N° échantillon`, 1, textLength)
```

The problem is the text length can also vary inside some datasets, so I need to adapt `textLength` for each entry.

I tried something like this

```
substr(data$`N° échantillon`, 1, which(strsplit(data[,"N° échantillon"], "") == "-")[2] - 1)
```

But of course I get the error

> data[, "N° échantillon"] is not a character chain

Is there a way to access the position of the data during the execution of the substr function?

As asked by a comment:

The input could be

| N° échantillon | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001-001-something | b | c |
| 001-002-something | b | c |
| 999-999-something | b | c |
| 001-0001-something | b | c |

The output would then be

| N° échantillon | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001-001 | b | c |
| 001-002 | b | c |
| 999-999 | b | c |
| 001-0001 | b | c |

But the actual code would give 001-000|b|c for the last line.

Comment: Could you provide example input and output? I think what you trying to do is: substring up to 2nd appearance of dash "-"?

Comment: Yes. For example the input could be `001-0001-something` and the output `001-0001`.
In general, the number of characters before the second dash vary only between dataframes. For example it can be 2 characters, a dash, 5 characters, a dash and something.
In some dataframes, the number of characters vary inside of it. Typically when I get `99-9999-something`, it'll be followed by `01-00001-something`.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/44934703/680068

Comment: Try: `sapply(strsplit(x, "-", fixed = TRUE), function(i) paste(i[1:2], collapse = "-"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `regex`:

```
library(stringr)
stringr::str_extract("test - test2 - test3","^(.*?-.*)?-")
"test - test2 -"
```

EDIT : which leads in this case, after adaptation by OP to:

```
data$`N° échantillon` <- gsub("^(.*?-.*?)-.*$", "\\1", data$`N° échantillon`)
```

Comment: I adapted your answer, but it worked like this: ```gsub("^(.*?-.*)-", 1, data$`N° échantillon`)```. Thank you very much!

Comment: I meant gsub("^(.*?-.*?)_.*$", "\\1", data$`N° échantillon`). I'll make a new answer to detail it in a clean way.

Comment: I didn't know I can't create an answer after validating. So here is what I wanted to post:

```data$`N° échantillon` <- gsub("^(.*?-.*?)-.*$", "\\1", data$`N° échantillon`)```

This regex will replace all the characters of each entry by all the characters before the second dash, even if the number of characters before the second dash vary.